# Why does event listener not get called?

Tags: events, jsf, icefaces, menuitem

I'm using **ice:menuPopup** to dynamically create menus on tree nodes. In jsf page I've something like this

```
  <f:facet name="content">
     <ice:panelGroup id="faccont" style="display: inline" menuPopup="qtaPupMenu"><ice:menuPopup imageDir="/images">
           <ice:menuItems  id="qtaPupMenu" value="#{item.userObject.menuModel}"/>
   . . .
```

Menu items are dynamically created by this code:

```
  public List<MenuItem> getMenuModel() {
    List<MenuItem> items = new LinkedList<MenuItem>();
    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
    mi.setValue("menu text");    
    ExpressionFactory expf = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    MethodExpression mthd = expf
    .createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{beanmodel.clickMenuContx}", void.class, new Class[] { ActionEvent.class });
    mi.setActionExpression(mex);           
    items.add(mi);
    return items;
  }
```

The problem is that the event listener "#{beanmodel.clickMenuContx}" never gets called.
I've tried also with methodBinding and setActionListener method of MenuItem, but doesn't work.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
It was missing the MenuItem **id** attribute.
I added

```
   mi.setId("myUniqueId");
```

and it works as expected.